# Double value becomes the opposite (0.5 becomes 5)

Tags: c#

Ok, so really weird problem I have here.

When I give `ingaveBox` a double value (0.5) and i press `"bereken"`, it adds 5.0 to my `gespaard` variable. I have absolutely no clue how this happens. I know there's a small mistake somewhere but i just can't get it figured out, when I debug the value changes from the moment where i put the comment.

Thanks in advance!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string path = @"C:\Users\Ragtox\Documents\Spaarpot\Spaarpot\gespaard.txt";
    private double vorigGespaard;
    private double toegevoegd;
    private double gespaard;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReadList();
    }

    void WriteList()
    {
        string[] createText = {gespaard.ToString()};
        File.WriteAllLines(path, createText);
    }

    void ReadList()
    {
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        vorigGespaard = Convert.ToDouble(readText[0]);
        vorigeBedragBox.Text = readText[0];
    }

    private void berekenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vorigeBedragBox.Text = vorigGespaard.ToString();
        gespaard = Convert.ToDouble(ingaveBox.Text) + vorigGespaard;
        //this is where 0.5 goes to 5.0
        gespaardBox.Text = gespaard.ToString();
        WriteList();
        ReadList();
    }

    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Culture problem check your settings on how decimal separator is set inside windows ;)

Comment: Does your system/locale use dots (.) or commas (,) for decimal separators?

Comment: My god i feel so stupid now.. i never expected that it would be something this simple..

Comment: Yeh, in some cultures 5.000 == 5000 and so 0.5 is similar to typing 0,5 and having it convert to 5 because it looks like a misplaced comma

Comment: Go read Jon Skeet's OMG Ponies!  http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/

Comment: @Aron i giggled, love the presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's been said, the issue could well stem from the [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo) that your machine is running in. In general, you should **ALWAYS** persist and depersist values in an [invariant culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) so that values saved in one language can be read in successfully on another language.

Otherwise, if, say a Brazilian Portuguese ([language code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052) `pt-br`) user saves the value `"123,456"` (which is how one hundred and twenty three and four hundred and fifty six thousandths would be represented in Portuguese), a user reading it in, say, British English (language code `en-gb`) would interpret it as one hundred and twenty three **thousand**, four hundred and fifty six (i.e. a factor of one thousand out).

---

I've modified your code to use [`Double.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045) and [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw) to save the values in the invariant culture.

```
void WriteList()
{
    // save in invariant culture
    string[] createText = {gespaard.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)};
    File.WriteAllLines(path, createText);
}

void ReadList()
{
    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    // read from invariant culture
    bool parsed = double.TryParse(readText[0], NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out vorigGespaard);
    if ( !parsed )
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to parse " + readText[0] + " as a double");

    // use the current culture to display the string
    vorigeBedragBox.Text = vorigGespaard.ToString();
}

private void berekenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vorigeBedragBox.Text = vorigGespaard.ToString();

    // get the value from its representation in the current culture
    gespaard = double.Parse(ingaveBox.Text) + vorigGespaard;

    // use the current culture to display the string
    gespaardBox.Text = gespaard.ToString();

    WriteList();
    ReadList();
}
```

---

*This is a minor inconvenience compared to a real problem I have seen where the calendar was assumed to be [Gregorian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) - this broke when I tried setting the culture to* `th` (Thai) *- they use the [Buddhist calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_calendar), which is ~543 years ahead. Its the year 2558 in that calendar - as you can imagine, not converting dates into [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) caused some problems...*